# for loop not working in JavaScript while Second Attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I got stuck in a very strange problem need help.
Actually i am trying to assign some value to dynamically generated input fields. So i tried the following code snippet. I mean to say in first step i only need to assign value for first 10 IDs and then again if assigning some other values to rest of IDs then it fails

**JavaScript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function callAssignMark() {

        var rightMarkVal = $("#rightMarkVal").val();
        var wrongMarkVal = $("#wrongMarkVal").val();
        var initial= $("#from").val();
        var last= $("#to").val();
        console.log('fromWhere--'+initial);
        console.log('to---'+last);
        alert('Before Loop');
        for (var i = initial; i <= last; i++) {
            $('#rightMark_' + i ).val(rightMarkVal);
            $('#wrongMark_' + i ).val(wrongMarkVal);
            $('#selectData_' + i).prop('checked', 'checked');
        }
        $("#from").val('');
        $("#to").val('');
    }

</script>
```

The above JavaScript code working fine in first attempt means when I assign some value to `initial` and `last` variable then the loop iterates and works as expected and assign desired values to dynamically generated input fields, But now the problem is when I assign new value to `initial` and `last` variable then the `loop` not able to iterate any more. 
And one more thing I want tell you all that all the dynamic IDs of input fields are generated correctly and I'm also getting the values which is going to be assigned to the input fields on second attempt and my HTML looks like following.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>From</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="" id="from" type="text" placeholder="from" value="" />
        <label>To</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="" id="to" type="text" placeholder="to" value="" />
        <input name="rightMarkVal" id="rightMarkVal" type="text" placeholder="positive Value" value="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input name="wrongMarkVal" id="wrongMarkVal" type="text" placeholder="Negative value" value="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Assign Marks" onclick="callAssignMark()">
      </li>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </ul>
  </div>

  <c:set var="counter" value="0" scope="page" />

  <div>
    <table>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckBox">
      </th>
      <th>Right Marks</th>
      <th>Wrong Marks</th>
      <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="list" items="${List}" varStatus="loop">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <c:out value="${counter = counter+1 }" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <form:checkbox path="qId" id="selectData_${counter}" value="${list.id}">
              </form:checkbox>
            </td>
            <td>
              <form:input path="rightMark" id="rightMark_${counter}" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <form:input path="wrongMark" id="wrongMark_${counter}" value="" />
            </td>

          </tr>
        </c:forEach>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to find out where is the problem so please help me.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If I add more rows statically, your code is working fine. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1s8zeyq/)

Comment: What do you mean by assigning new values to initial and last variable? Do you mean entering new value in respected input fields and click on button which calls callAssignMark()?

Comment: @Abhishek yea, It is working for me too.

Comment: @Pradeep i mean to say in first step i only need to assign value for first 10 Ids then again if assigning some other values to rest of ids then it fails